# How to change x-axis value?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a problem with change x-axis value on plot.
I have to plot a 5 different values:

```
 1. 0-366
 2. 366-732
 3. 732-1098
 4. 1089-1464
 5. 1464-1829
```

But when I plot second values it start from 366 and end at 732. I want to plot second values from start(1-366), not from 732 to 1098 such on picture.
How to do it?
[image]

Comment: What does the documentation for the plotting function that you are using say? There is probably a parameter with a name like `xlim`.

Comment: Can you provide your current code formatted as a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: @Nuageux I Add a picture above

Comment: subtract the minimum of the range(a,b)..

Comment: This data is reading from CSV file. I have 1829 rows with 5 different data split in one file.

Comment: @Szymon You add a picture, not the code as requested ([mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)).

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have 2 columns in your data - `second` and `TempF`. If this is true, then the following could be one approach:

1. First slice the required values from the `second` column:

   `myvalues = range(366,732+1)
    df = df[df['second']isin(myvalues)]`
2. Next, plot the 2 columns from the sliced `DF`:

   `df3.plot(x='second', y='TempF', label='MeanT')`

If your data has a different format (eg. data splits???), you should post a sample dataset in your question.